# How to get the list of Alert tones in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to get the list of Alert tones in iOS (in **Objective C**). Currently what I am doing is getting the files in `/System/Library/Audio/UISounds`. But that directory contains many sound files. (Ringtones, keypad sounds, .....)

I had to do this in Android and it was easy in Android. Needed to pass "**RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION**".

But do not how to do it in iOS. I have seen other apps (e.g. Whatsapp, FB) shows a list of Alert tones.

### Please help.

(I think this is not a duplicate question as suggested. I know how to get the list of Ringtones. But I want know how to filter Alert sounds.)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Question suggested as duplicate was asked 7 years ago and answer that it has is "it can't be done".
Apps mentioned by OP do it, so it certainly is possible now. I am also looking for an answer.